# Remove parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can someone help me solve this problem.
I want loop through class 'row' and delete entire class 'card-col' that contain id=x2 or x3.

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x1"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x2"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x3"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

expected result something like this.
what jquery i can use ?

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x1"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x4"></div></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Have you tried out something in JQuery ? Please post your code, community will be happy to help/guide from there

Answer (score 1):

Go quickly trough the jQuery docs:

[Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)  how to get an element using the right selectors
[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) test up the DOM tree finding the closest matching element
[.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) yep.

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM is now ready

  $("#x2, #x3").closest(".card-col").remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="card-col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card" id="x1">x1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card" id="x2">x2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card" id="x3">x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The other way around, you can target first all `.card-col` and that use `:not(:has(#x1))` to filter and than remove

https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/
https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM is now ready
  
  $(".card-col:not(:has(#x1))").remove();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="card-col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card" id="x1">x1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card" id="x2">x2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card" id="x3">x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank Roco, this work perfectly

Comment: @RamaMagfirah you're welcome

Comment: how, if i want just keep 'x1' and remove 'x2' 'x3' and other unknown id/class ?

Comment: @RamaMagfirah see edit

Comment: $(".card :not(#x1)").closest(".card-col").remove();

code doesn't work, entire class removed

Comment: using "not(:has(#x1))" work perfect. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could use `parents()` :

```
$("#x2, #x3").parents(".card-col").remove();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#x2, #x3").parents(".card-col").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x1">x1</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x2">x2</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x3">x3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="card-col">
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card" id="x4">x4</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.closest()` is quicker cause it stops iterating DOM nodes after a match is found.

Comment: That true.. but in such simple cases difference is in some milliseconds...